# What reasons do Brexiteers have for wanting to be part of TPP?

Tags: united-kingdom, european-union, brexit, international

Many [Brexiteers don't want to be part of an economic bloc run from Brussels](https://www.economist.com/the-economist-explains/2017/07/14/does-it-make-sense-to-refer-to-eu-officials-as-unelected-bureaucrats). Instead, [some want to be part of TPP](https://twitter.com/LiamFox/status/1049208009879179264?ref_src=twsrc%5Etfw), an economic bloc run from New Zealand. What reasons have those Brexiteers given for wanting to join TPP (while being opposed to being an EU customs union member)?

Specifically, what does TPP do right that the EU customs union does wrong?

Comment: Could you provide a source that some significant number or faction of those in favor of Brexit support membership in the TPP as a policy position?

Comment: Quick Google search came up with -

https://asia.nikkei.com/Editor-s-Picks/Interview/UK-keen-for-TPP-entry-and-Japan-trade-deal-after-Brexit

https://www.ft.com/content/73943036-efa9-11e7-b220-857e26d1aca4

https://www.theguardian.com/politics/2018/jan/03/britain-in-talks-to-join-the-tpp-to-boost-trade-after-brexit

https://www.smh.com.au/politics/federal/britain-keen-to-join-australia-in-trans-pacific-partnership-20180926-p5063d.html

Comment: Articles to date seem to be coming from TPP countries, e.g. Japan saying that UK would be welcomed, that does NOT necessarily say those in the UK who preferred exiting from the EU have any strong desire to join TPP.

Comment: Furthermore, the TPP is "defunct", so I'm not sure the question really is meaningful.

Comment: @Burt_Harris  The other countries have been moving forward with TPP without the US.  It's only defunct as a US-led initiative.

Comment: The question got a close vote. I think it's a good question, but it could be phrased in a way that seems like it's not asking for opinions. Therefore, I rephrased it. if it doesn't properly reflect your question or view points, feel free to revert (some of) the edit.

Comment: @Burt_Harris I added a link to a tweet from dr. Liam Fox, he is the SoS for international trade. In his tweet, he wrote: *'Delighted to see his encouragement for UK joining CPTPP in @ FT today.'* Perhaps not indicative of a 'strong desire', but it's certainly more appreciative than [his view on being in or close to the EU](https://www.theguardian.com/politics/2018/aug/05/liam-fox-says-no-deal-brexit-now-more-likely-than-an-agreement). ;)

Comment: @JJJ yes I realise the question wasn't quite phrased neutral enough. I've edited it again to put emphasis on the customs union rather than the EU. There are lots of reasons why you might not like the latter, but not liking the former while still liking TPP is odd to me, especially given the geographic distances involved. Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

The obvious answer is that the European Union requires [free movement of labor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Freedom_of_movement_for_workers_in_the_European_Union) and the [Trans-Pacific Partnership](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trans-Pacific_Partnership) does not.  Note that generally, the United Kingdom does want a free trade agreement with Europe.  It's the free movement of labor clause of the European Union that has been the sticking point.  A lot of the current negotiating between the UK and EU is over how trade will be managed going forward.  In particular, the question of a customs union is critical.

See [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Causes_of_the_vote_in_favour_of_Brexit) as an example source for reasons to leave.

Comment: That's an interesting answer. [UK employers actually struggle to fill vacancies](https://www.bbc.com/news/business-45162132).

Comment: Your answer doesn't make sense. Freedom of movement is a core part of a free trade deal, as companies need to move staff around and visas are non-tariff barriers. In other words the UK doesn't want a free trade deal, it wants a limited trade deal.

Comment: @user You can write visa rules that make it just as easy for a company to send a representative as a delivery of goods, but that isn't "free movement of labor".

Answer (score -2):

Brexiteers oppose free trade because it includes things they don't like.

For example, freedom of movement of workers. Companies need to move staff around and hire across borders, and having barriers like a strict visa system based on quotas or points creates a barrier to trade.

Another key aspect of a free trade deal is a customs union that removes customs barriers for goods. This requires both parties to agree to common customs rules for goods coming from outside the union, which is something they oppose with the EU customs union.

In other words Brexieers prefer a limited deal with barriers to restrict trade, for ideological reasons.

Comment: *Most* free-trade deals only specify goods and services, not labor. It's only the EU that is lumping goods, services, capital and labor together, and even then, they don't label the collection of those "free trade", but "freedom of movement"

Comment: @Caleth that is incorrect, free trade deals typically include things like not needing a visa for short visits and a preferential system for permanent workers. In fact India has indicated that in order to do such a deal with the UK it would want freedom of movement rights to be included. What you describe is a basic trade deal that just removes tariffs and maybe agrees some common standards, the latter being something Brexiteers also don't want.

Comment: There's a *big* difference between visas that allow you to enter a country for the purpose of conducting trade and visas that allow you to settle, gain local employment, etc. Free movement of *labor* is the second kind. You are confusing it with *a form of* free movement of *people*

Comment: @Caleth freedom of movement is what India is asking for. Companies want to be able to move staff around. They want them to be able to work in the other country, which requires a visa even if it is temporary. See the deal that the EU did with Canada for an example of a normal trade deal that isn't free trade because it only covers goods and some services.